# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Hello I am working with laravel and livewire and I'm trying to resolve this error for a chat room, can anyone help me please? :

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Unable to
> resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $message ]] in class
> App\Http\Livewire\ChatRoom

this is the concerned function in **LettresController.php**

```
    public function ChoisirLettresAléatoiresDuReserve(){
        // Messages de la btcom
        $message=Message::all();
        $user_id = auth()->id();
        // check if there is game in the request
        if (!request()->has('game')) {
            return redirect()->route('game.select');
        }
        // getting game ID and fetching game
        $game = $this->get_game_by_id((int)request()->get('game'));
    
        // check if the game has finished or is still running
        if ($this->check_game_finished($game)) {
    
            $this->update_game_timer($game, $user_id);
    
    
    // user has used up his chevalet, so we need to update with new
            $position = $this->user_chevalet_position($game, $user_id);
            if ($position === null) {
                // user might have entered a game id but was never part of the game
                return redirect()->route('game.select');
            }
    
            // get if the player has no more playing piece left
            $user_chevalet = $this->get_user_chevalet($game, $user_id, $position);
    
            $valeur = $this->generate_valeur($user_chevalet);
            $game = $this->get_game_by_id((int)request()->get('game'));
    
    
            return view('jeu')->with(compact('game', 'valeur', 'position','message'));
    
        }
        return redirect()->route('game.ended')->with(['Resultat' => 'Game Ended']);
    
    }
```

and I am using **livewire**
**livewire.ChatRoom.php**

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    use App\Traits\GameTraits;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Carbon;
    
    class ChatRoom extends Component
    {
    
        public $newMessage;
        public $photo;
        public $messages;
    
        public function mount($message){
            // dd($message);
            $this->messages = $message;
        }
    
        public function addMessage($message)
        {
            if($this->newMessage==''){
                return;
            }
            array_unshift($this->messages,[
                'contenu' => $this->newMessage,
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(),
                'user_id'=> 'Ness'
            ]);
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.chat-room');
        }
    }
```

**chat-room.blade.php**

```
    <div class="container" id="positionbt"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bootstrap snippets bootdeys" >
                <div class="widget-container scrollable list rollodex">
                    <div class="heading" id="btc">
                        <span class="fa"></span> Boite de communication
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="chat">
                        <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left" >
                                <img  width="40" height="40" src="{{ asset('img/scrabblelogo.png') }}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                            </span>
                                <div class="chat-body clearfix" class="text">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <strong class="primary-font">!Aide</strong> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <p>
                                            Bonjour! Afin de pouvoir effectuer les tâches ci-dessous, vous pouvez utiliser ces 5 commandes:<br>
                                            <b>1. Placer un mot:</b> !placer ligne colonne (h|v) mot<br>
                                            <b>2. Changer une lettre:</b> !changer lettre<br>
                                            <b>3. Passer le tour à un autre joueur:</b> !passer<br>
                                            <b>4. Afficher le menu d'aide:</b> !aide<br>
                                            <b>5. Quitter menu d'aide:</b> !quitter<br>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            @foreach ($messages as $message)
    
                            <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                                <img  width="40" height="40" src="{{  $message->post_by->photo }}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                            </span>
                                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <strong class="primary-font">{{ $message->post_by->nick }}</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>{{ $message->created_at }}</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        {{ $message->contenu }}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <form class="panel-footer" id="msg" wire:submit.prevent="addMessage">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Tapez votre message ici..." wire:model="newMessage"/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top: 8px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" type="submit">
                                    Envoyer</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I included this in **jeu.blade.php**

```
<div class="btcom">
    <livewire:chat-room :message="$message"/>
</div>
```

and my root in **web.php** is below:

```
    Route::get('/jeu', [App\Http\Controllers\LettresController::class, 'ChoisirLettresAléatoiresDuReserve'])->name('jeu');
```

Comment: Route::get('/jeu/{message}', [App\Http\Controllers\LettresController::class, 'ChoisirLettresAléatoiresDuReserve'])->name('jeu'); ???

Comment: yes it works even before adding the live chat and before compacting the 'message' within the function ChoisirLettresAléatoiresDuReserve() but the problem is not with the route but with binding and I'm looking for how to do the binding because still, I didn't find any working solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Ok, trying to understand the goal you pursuit you can handle like this, after we can do by better way

```
return redirect()->route('jeu.message',['game'=> $game, 'valeur'=>$valeur, 'position' => $position,'message' => $message]);
```

in web.php

```
Route::get('/jeu/{message}', function($message){
  // dd($message);
  return view('jeu',['message'=>$message]);
})->name('jeu.message');
```

This way, you can check if inside the method when this route is load it's passing the message value and you inject it into the blade and this way can be bind by the nested component

Comment: This actually raises another error Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: jeu.message] [URI: jeu/{message}] [Missing parameters: "id":*,"user_id":*,"game_id":*,"position":*,"contenu":"*","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"*","updated_at":"*",....

Comment: return redirect()->route('jeu.message',['message' => $message]); pass only the message parameter to see. Check the dd inside the route to see if is binding the data inside

Comment: Back to the 1st error, the problem here is that I'm dealing with two tables games and messages

Comment: Then be specific with the message table or model that you are going to bind to the chat component: public MessageClass $message; This way you don't need the mount method

Comment: I didn't really get your idea

Comment: Help me to understand. In this ChoisirLettresAléatoiresDuReserve method you retrieve all the message by $message=Message::all() statement but you don't do anything with, just bind this to the jeu view. In this jeu.blade.php only is render for the livewire directive??? In this case, you don't need bind the :message="$message"/>. Do this in the mount method instead...$this->message = Message::all(); Hope you understand better my idea

Comment: softly, particularly I think you don't need bind to the nested component the whole $message collection if you can do it in the livewire component and bind this to component blade for be showed